# Spacing out stacked bars in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am trying to do a stacked bar chart with only one bar in Chart.js using JS, CSS, and HTML. This is the chart I have constructed so far:
[image]

And I am trying to make it look like the following:

[image]

I don't know how or if its possible in Chart.js to space out the bars like I did above and add the bracket labels below the chart. TYIA

```js
var len_one = 0.02;
var len_two = 0.05;
var len_three = 0.72;
var len_four = 0.16;
var len_five = 0.05;

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [0],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'red-low',
            data: [len_one],
            backgroundColor: ['#ab3025'],
            barThickness: 50,
            borderSkipped: false,
            borderRadius: {
                bottomLeft: 3,
                topLeft: 3,
                topRight: 3,
                bottomRight: 3
            },
        }, {
            label: 'rose-low', 
            data: [len_two],
            backgroundColor: ['#d59792'],
            barThickness: 50,
            borderSkipped: false,
            borderRadius: {
                bottomLeft: 3,
                topLeft: 3,
                topRight: 3,
                bottomRight: 3
            },
        }, {
            label: 'Target',
            data: [len_three],
            backgroundColor: ['#44c973'],
            barThickness: 50,
            borderSkipped: false,
            borderRadius: 3,
        }, {
            label: 'high-yellow',
            data: [len_four],
            backgroundColor: ['#f9c63d'],
            barThickness: 50, 
            borderSkipped: false,
            borderRadius: {
                bottomLeft: 3,
                topLeft: 3,
                topRight: 3,
                bottomRight: 3
            },
        }, {
            label: 'high-orange',
            data: [len_five],
            backgroundColor: ['#f5a000'],
            barThickness: 50,
            borderSkipped: false,
            borderRadius: {
                bottomLeft: 3,
                topLeft: 3,
                topRight: 3,
                bottomRight: 3
            },
        }]
    },
    options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        events: [], 
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        layout: {
            padding: 20,
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true,
                display: false,
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                stacked: true,
                display: false

            },
        },
    },

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Chart that displays the time in ranges-->
        <div class="col-6 offset-3 my-5" id="time_in_range">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding adding spaces between the bars, I wasn't either able to find any direct configuration that allowed such behavior.

My first thought was to add borders and make them invisible, however you wouldn't see the effect of `borderRadius`.

Then, I come to another approach that interleaves the dataset object with a 'fake' data with transparent color, which has customizable length acting as the gap. With the use of `flatMap`, you can construct such interleaved array.

Also putting everything in the outer object, you can avoid redundant code.

```
 datasets: {
      bar: {
        barThickness: 50,
        borderSkipped: false,
        borderRadius: {
          topLeft: 3,
          topRight: 3,
          bottomLeft: 3,
          bottomRight: 3
        }
      }
    },
```

That corresponds to:

```js
var len_one = 0.02;
var len_two = 0.05;
var len_three = 0.72;
var len_four = 0.16;
var len_five = 0.05;

// Change this to adjust gap size
var len_separator = 0.05

const separator = {
  label: 'sepataror',
  data: [len_separator],
  backgroundColor: ['transparent'],
}

let data = [{
    label: 'red-low',
    data: [len_one],
    backgroundColor: ['#ab3025']
  },
  {
    label: 'rose-low',
    data: [len_two],
    backgroundColor: ['#d59792'],
  }, {
    label: 'Target',
    data: [len_three],
    backgroundColor: ['#44c973'],
  }, {
    label: 'high-yellow',
    data: [len_four],
    backgroundColor: ['#f9c63d'],
  }, {
    label: 'high-orange',
    data: [len_five],
    backgroundColor: ['#f5a000'],
  }
].flatMap(x => [x, { ...separator}])

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [0],
    datasets: data,
  },
  options: {
    datasets: {
      bar: {
        barThickness: 50,
        borderSkipped: false,
        borderRadius: {
          topLeft: 3,
          topRight: 3,
          bottomLeft: 3,
          bottomRight: 3
        }
      }
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    events: [],
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: 20
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        display: false
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stacked: true,
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Chart that displays the time in ranges-->
  <div class="col-6 offset-3 my-5" id="time_in_range">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

About the grouped labels with brackets, I'm not sure it is possible without a plugin or something fancier.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above was a correct solution to my problem, but that answer had been posted I figured out a different way to do it. I made 0.01 size bars in between each colored bar and made the color the same as the background of the webpage I was working on. That fixed my issue as well.